# AngularJS updating object attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to to update the attribute of an onbject in angularjs array of object.

I have the folowing array of object:

```
  $scope.formes= [
{id: 0, geo: 0,cx:0, cy:0, b:0, h:0, r:0, d:0, a:0, ax:0, ay:0, val: 0}
 ];
```

The values of each attribute are set to 0 by default until the user type in a new value in a field. Some values are updated after the user add a new objet or hit a button. This app is used to calculate the center of basic geometric shapes and there moments. Just fyi.

This is the function that is running when the user add an object.

```
$scope.ajoutForme = function(){

     $scope.formes.a = parseInt($scope.formes.b) * parseInt($scope.formes.h); /// not working

  $scope.formes.push({
    id: $scope.nbrForme++ //just adding and new id
  });  
}
```

Before I add the objet I want to update some values with calculations. For exemple in this case I what to set the value of `a` with `b*h`.

I have try

```
$scope.formes[nbrForme].h = parseInt($scope.formes[nbrForme].b) * parseInt($scope.formes[nbrForme].h); //This is working but only the first time I press the button??
```

`nbrForme` is = to  the id of the element I am working on and gets incremented when I add a new object.

**Complete Controler**

```js
var moment = angular.module('moment',[]);
var nbrForme = 0;

moment.controller('momentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.nbrForme = nbrForme;
  
 $scope.formes= [
{id: 0, geo: 0,cx:0, cy:0, b:0, h:0, r:0, d:0, a:0, ax:0, ay:0, val: 0}
 ];


$scope.ajoutForme = function(){

  $scope.formes[nbrForme].a = parseInt($scope.formes[nbrForme].b) * parseInt($scope.formes[nbrForme].h); /// only work once
 
  $scope.formes.push({
 id: $scope.nbrForme++
  });  
}
}
}]);
```

Comment: Please provide some more code... Where are you initializing the $scope.object? inside a controler? If so how does the controller look like and where / how are you manipulation the attr3 attribute? Inside a method? If so is the method called?

Comment: Updated with my actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object definition is wrong:

```
$scope.object = [
    {id:0, attr1:2, attr2:4, attr3:0},
    {id:1, attr1:2, attr2:4, attr3:0},
    {id:2, attr1:2, attr2:4, attr3:0}
];
```

Note a added `,` to separate the elements of the array.

**Edit:**

You wrote that this line doesn't work `$scope.formes.a = parseInt($scope.formes.b) * parseInt($scope.formes.h);`
This is because `$scope.formes` is an array, so you must reference to a specific object inside the array that has the `a`/`b`/`h` property. The question is which one?

If it's the first index in the array you'll do

```
$scope.formes[0].a = parseInt($scope.formes[0].b) * parseInt($scope.formes[0].h);
```

The last element:

```
var lastIndex = $scope.formes.length - 1;
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    $scope.formes[lastIndex].a = parseInt($scope.formes[lastIndex].b) * parseInt($scope.formes[lastIndex].h);
}
```

If `$scope.nbrForme` is the ID of the element you're currently working on, then you need to decrease its value by 1, because you start with the value of 1, and the first index of an array is 0:

```
$scope.formes[$scope.nbrForme - 1].a = parseInt($scope.formes[$scope.nbrForme - 1].b) * parseInt($scope.formes[$scope.nbrForme - 1].h);
```

Comment: Yeah sorry i have updated my code with the actual code

Comment: It's illegal to do `$scope.formes.a` because `$scope.formes` is an array. So you must reference to a specific index inside that array. Can you show us the complete code of the controller?

Comment: Thank you sir this is working. I forgot to add $scope in front of nbrForm